# Change directory to subfolder with single quotes and exclamation mark

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm trying to navigate down to a subfolder in a bash shell. The name of the subfolder is: 
Let's Go Play!

I cannot figure out how to escape the single quote (apostrophe) or the exclamation point. 
I have tried

```
cd "Let's Go Play\!"
cd "Let\'s Go Play\!"
```

Thanks.

Comment: let `bash` autocomplete it for you with tabbing...

Answer (score 3):

The correct form is

```
cd "Let's Go Play!"
```

Inside double quotes, backslashes are not special unless they come before a newline, a quote, a backslash, a dollar sign or a backtick. Backslash-newline is removed altogether; a backslash followed by one of the other four characters in that list is removed and the character loses its special significance.

Inside single quotes, backslashes are never removed and have no special significance. Consequently, it is impossible to insert a single quote into a single-quoted string and so there is no single-quoted form of the above `cd` command. However, you can concatenate words, so you could write:

```
cd 'Let'"'"'s Go Play!'
```

Outside of quoted words, backslashes are more general. A backslash followed by any character other than a newline character is removed from the input and the following character becomes an ordinary character (even if it were ordinary already). Backslash-newline is removed entirely from the input, so that there is no way to insert a newline character into an unquoted string.

So you could have written:

```
cd Let\'s\ Go\ Play\!
```

But the double-quoted version one seems simpler.

Exclamations points are an extension to the Posix standard (the above rules comes directly from the Posix standard), and the bash implementation is a bit quirky and sometimes really annoying. Exclamation points introduce history expansion, unless they are inside single quotes, are preceded by a backslash, or are followed by whitespace or either an equals sign or (if shell option `extglob` is enabled) an open parenthesis. Inside double quotes, an exclamation point is also not special just before the closing quote. (You can change the history expansion character to something other than an exclamation point so technically I should write "the history expansion character".)

Even though a backslash makes an exclamation mark unspecial, the backslash is not removed from the input stream unless it would have been removed by the Posix rules. So the exclamation point in

```
echo "a\!b"
```

is an ordinary character (it is preceded by a backslash), but the backslash is also an ordinary character (it is not followed by one of the characters in the double-quote list), so the result is

```
a\!b
```

(Although I copied those rules from the bash manual, I know there are some other cases where history expansion is suppressed, such as when the exclamation point is part of a parameter expansion such as `$!` or `${!name}`. And I think there are more of these exceptions that I can't remember off-hand.)

I find all that so annoying, and I rely so little on history expansion, that I simply turn it off by adding `set +H` to my bash startup file `~/.bashrc`. If you turn history expansion off, then exclamation points lose all special significance. However, there are people who seem to really like history expansion, and if you're one of them, more power to you.

Comment: Egad, the exclamation point rules are much messier than I realized!